# Moving actor with constant value in libgdx

Tags: java, android, libgdx

I am trying to move an actor from left side to right side of the
device screen and it will disapper when it reach right side. The 
game is only in portrait mode. If the game is palyed on 720 and 
1080 wide screens (assume both devices have same dpi),
user with latter device will have more time to see the actor.
The question I want to ask is how to move my actor to right side of
the screen and disappear at the same time on all screen sizes (720, 1080, 1280 or whatever). The game is targeted only on android. Following is the code I am testing to move my actor,

```
@Override
public void act(float delta) {
    super.act(delta);
    setX(getX() + 1);
}
```

Comment: Instead of doing a pixel based movement do a distance based movement. Use a coordinate system in your game, do all the movement on this system and transform the coordinate system to pixel coordinates depending on screen resolution.

Comment: Meaning that when e.g. you move 1 unit this translates to 1 pixel on a 1000 pixel screen and 2 pixels on a 2000 pixel screen (or some other transformation as you wish)

Comment: @Ben Will you please elaborate or do you have some reference or link or something about that?

Comment: On a sidenote: The delta in your `act` method is there for a reason, it shows a timespan. You should change your movement based on the timespan. Else you get frame dependent movement speed.

Comment: Well basically you want to decouple all drawing and all calculation. You first do a calculation step using your internal coordinate system. Then in the drawing step you check for your resolution and transform based on that.

Comment: I'm quite sure that this is covered in tutorials. Get a good book, read through it. It's the best thing you can do here probably.

Comment: @Ben What do you mean internal coordinate system?

Comment: I'm handling different screen resolution with camera (zoom) property. Everything else is the same for all screen resolutions. Basically I work with one "virtual" screen which is the same for all devices.

Comment: @MilanG What is virtual screen?

Comment: Read the article on Viewports in the LibGDX wiki documentation.

Answer (score 0):

So, I assume that my "virtual" screen is MAP_WIDTH x MAP_HEIGHT and all the drawing I do like every screen is in those dimensions. Then I just set camera zoom like this:

```
public final float MAP_WIDTH = 1440;
public final float MAP_HEIGHT = 2960;

private void setCamera(){
    screenWidth =Gdx.graphics.getWidth();
    screenHeight = Gdx.graphics.getHeight();


    camera.setToOrtho(false, screenWidth, screenHeight);

    float zoomW = MAP_WIDTH / screenWidth;
    float zoomH = MAP_HEIGHT / screenHeight;
    camera.zoom = (zoomW < zoomH)?zoomW:zoomH;
    camera.position.x = MAP_WIDTH/2;
    camera.position.y = MAP_HEIGHT/2;
    camera.update();
    batch.setProjectionMatrix(camera.combined);
}
```

So no matter what real screen resolution is my "virtual" screen will be displayed well ("full screen"). That is...if aspect ratio is the same it will fill real screen 100% and if not...some part will be clipped off, but I tend not to keep important screen parts at screen borders.

I do that trick in all my games and it works fine, i.e. in the latest one: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.mgsoft.reversi